# How to deal(compare) with input divided by space c++

Tags: c++, input, access-violation, palindrome

I have no clue why compiler is throwing an access violation inputing ile=1000. 
I know that in other inputs probably the compiler inputs sentences so then it would look like sentence1 sentence2 but in this sentences words are also divided by space so I totally have no idea how to get this input

```
std::operator>><char,std::char_traits<char> >()
_Istr = nullptr+117
_Str = nullptr+117
_State = 0
_Str0 = 0xE76A2E98 -> "dqecjdxmyweglskxfpnqqups..."
_Ok = std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::sentry{...}
```

I'm not sure which type of input should I try. I have to check whether inputs are palindromes. Example input:

```
12
a a
b a
abc cba
abc abc
abc bac
abc xyz
aabc abac
aabc abc
abc aabc
aabbcc abcccc
```

I tried to do this by cin, any as I descriped at the top it throws acces violation dunno why.
Getline doesn't work as words are 1 input separated by space
Getchar throws another FAIL_STACK error. Any ideas? My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

void qsort(char tab[], int min, int max)
{
    if(min<max)
    {
        int min_min = min;
        for(int i=min+1;i<=max;i++)
        {
            if(tab[i]<tab[min])
            {
                swap(tab[++min_min],tab[i]);
            }
        }
        swap(tab[min],tab[min_min]);
        qsort(tab,min,min_min-1);
        qsort(tab,min_min+1,max);
    }
}
bool sprawdz(char tab[],char tab2[])
{
    for(int i=0;i<strlen(tab);i++)
    {
        if(tab[i]!=tab2[i])
        {
            return false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    char tablica1[100];
    char tablica2[100];
    int ile;
    cin>>ile;
    for(int i=0;i<ile;i++)
    {
        cin>>tablica1>>tablica2;
        qsort(tablica1,0,strlen(tablica1)-1);
        qsort(tablica2,0,strlen(tablica2)-1);
        if(sprawdz(tablica1,tablica2))
        {
            cout<<"TAK"<<endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<"NIE"<<endl;
        }
        memset(tablica1,0,100);
        memset(tablica2,0,100);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is this a homework? Are you not allowed to use certain standard library facilities?

Comment: well that's a kind of a task, in my opinion string and iostream libraries would be enough to do it

Comment: Are you truing to solve an online programming challenge? If so, please provide a URL of the challenge site. In my opinion trying to learn arrays and C style strings before you know how to use C++ facilities is a pointless waste of time. At any rate, if your program crashes, you need to show the input that leads to the crash. If you cannot reproduce the crash, we probably cannot help.

Comment: it's a task provided by my university and the only thing I have is:
input : number of word pairs
then 2 words in each line
task: tell if these words are palindromes and that's all
output: yes if they are palindromes, no if they aren't yes=TAK no=NIE in my code

Comment: 3 first tests are correct and then in the 4th test i have this error in the explanation

Comment: error throws line in which i have "cin>>tablica1>>tablica2" and that's all i know, problem is probably with accesion the memory that I am not able to but I have no clue why and where if I reset arrays every loop and input again

Comment: I don't know whether my program crashes as for iterations like 10-20 pairs of words it works properly, the university program "crashes" inputing 1000 loops and doesn't show where and how, it only outputs the memory adress that "crashes"

Comment: ACCESS_VIOLATION 0xE76C2000

Comment: Why is your `tablica1` size 100? Is that something given by the task or did you decide on this size because it works with some of your samples?

Comment: size is 100 as I don't know how long are given inputs